# ReferenceError: file is not defined - Suitescript

Tags: csv, import, netsuite, suitescript

I resolved some earlier issues and got the below script to validate and deploy.
However it fails and in the logs I see this error:

*ReferenceError: file is not defined [at Object.execute (/SuiteScripts/purchasing.js:11:9)]*

but my file is definitely there in that location and is defined in the script.

All help greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 */

define(['N/task'], 
function (task) {
function execute(scriptContext){
var scriptTask = task.create({taskType: task.TaskType.CSV_IMPORT});
scriptTask.mappingId = 212; 
var f = file.load('SuiteScripts/purchasing2.csv');
scriptTask.importFile = f;
var csvImportTaskId = scriptTask.submit();
};
return{
    execute: execute
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load the `N/file` module as well.

```js
define(['N/task', 'N/file'], function(task, file) {

  ....

})
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, this was the solution.